# How can i change the style of a REQUEST from another web page?

Tags: php, styles, request, echo, output

As you can see in the picture, there is the definition of the word HELLO from the site wordreference.com .

I desire urgently to eliminate objects i desired, for example the search bar, while maitaing the main definition. I also must be able to change the fontstyle, color, size, etc. of all of the text in wordreference's anwser.
[image]
 (...)

```
    echo "<iframe id='first' src='http://api.wordreference.com/definition/{$word}' 
          frameborder='0' 
          width='400px' 
          height='300px' 
          scrolling='yes'
          textcolor='red'
          border-style: none;></iframe>";

    ?>   
</body>
```

Comment: If that's in an `IFRAME` and that frame is in violation of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (in other words, originates from another site or sub domain more or less), you're out of luck from within the same page. Maybe from the service itself (through a configuration on your account?).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: See tags (namely, PHP). He's probably pulling the page serverside, then serving it as his own.

Comment: @Amadan - It is coming from `api.wordreference.com`, maybe it's a service? I think you're reading a little into it. He's `echo`ing an `iframe` statement, not streaming or using cURL to grab content. Maybe that's what they *want* in practice, but I don't see that (yet).

Comment: i failed to use cURL too, would you be so kind ot adapt it to this model please? @Amadan i would appreciate it immnesly

Answer (score 1):

They have an API specifically for this. You are using it incorrectly.

Check there [API Docs](http://www.wordreference.com/docs/api.aspx) and http://api.wordreference.com/1/json/enfr/grin

Parse the JSON response before you `echo` any HTML code.

Comment: how should i Parse efficently?